# Joining multiple tables in MYSQL returns nothing

Tags: mysql

So i have a table called db_computer. in this table there are columns for example Id, CPU, Geheugen.

I have two other tables: CPU, Geheugen. each of them have a column Id and Naam.

What i want to do is put the Id of the right CPU or Geheugen in my db_computer so that i can make a SELECT statement using an inner join to get The names matching the Id of those two colums.

```
SELECT pc.Id, c.Naam, mem.Naam From db_computer as pc
inner join cpu as c on c.Id = pc.CPU
inner join geheugen as mem on mem.Id = pc.Geheugen
where pc.id = 1;
```

But im getting nothing returned to me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post us the table data

Comment: fiddle us pleas http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/564240

Comment: Thanks Shawan, but I've been expecting you put the data too, not only the schema. You don't need put all data, just put one data that you have shure that should return something.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8eef0e

Comment: thanks already for looking into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your auto-incremented IDs are not matching up. In your query, you have `where pc.id=1` but because your `pc` table has `auto_increment=2`, the first record in `pc` has an id of 2 since there doesn't exist any record with `pc.id=1`.

Similarly, let's look at the following query:

```
SELECT pc.Id, c.Naam FROM db_computer as pc
inner join cpu as c on c.Id = pc.CPU
where pc.id = 1;
```

which is a simplified version of your query. In your `cpu` table, you have `auto-increment=4` so your first record has an `id = 4`. Because of this, when you try to join on `c.Id = pc.CPU`, nothing is returned since `c.Id=4` and `pc.CPU=1`. This is the same case for your inner join on `mem`.

Unless you have some particular reason for setting different auto-increments for each table, the easy way to fix this is to have all the tables have the same auth-increment value. When I set all your auto-increments to 1 in the schema, your query returns your desired answer.

Hope this helps.